# How to fix 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm working deep learning and for that I'm using a algorithm that will be using that to train my dataset. So, this is all I'm getting during running the code. can you help me to identify where I'm lacking.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-20-70463f35b888> in <module>
         45 #merge two encoded inputs with the l1 distance between them
         46 L1_distance = lambda x: K.abs(x[0]-x[1])
    ---> 47 both = merge([encoded_l,encoded_r], mode = L1_distance, output_shape=lambda x: x[0])
         48 prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',bias_initializer=b_init)(both)
         49 siamese_net = Model(input=[left_input,right_input],output=prediction)

    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: How is L1_distance imported?

Comment: L1_distance is a variable

Comment: See this answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/adhsbi/keras_mergelayer1_layer2_modemul/

Comment: it didn't work with the layers.

Comment: can you show code which makes problem ? in this line i see that only `merge()` is called so if you have module `merge`  (which is not function) then you can't use it as function `merge()`

Comment: see this code.

www.github.com/tabarkarajab/VPS/blob/master/one_shot.ipynb